# Enable mySQL remote connections port 3306 Plesk 11.5 CENTOS

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli, plesk

I am having problems connecting to our mysql server remotely. We have 2 servers both running Plesk 11.5 one of them is linux (IP 99.99.99.99) and the other is Windows R2 2008 (IP 88.88.88.88).

Note: These are not the true IP addresses but for security I have replaced them with those above.

I am trying to connect to the mysql server on the linux machine from the windows machine. I am connecting via PHP scripts using mysqli

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '99.99.99.99' (10060) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\oldburywells.co.uk\httpdocs\setup\includes\db.php on line 12
Failed to connect to MySQL: (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on '99.99.99.99' (10060)
```

The contents of /etc/my.cnf is below:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
# Forced OLD_PASSWORD format is turned OFF by Plesk
#old_passwords=1
port=3306
bind-address=99.99.99.99
# skip-networking

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

In the mysql database - db table the record for the host is this ignore the insert statement, this was the easiest way for me to display the options:

```
INSERT INTO `db` (`Host`, `Db`, `User`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Execute_priv`) VALUES
('%', 'designjazzsetup', 'designjazzsu', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y');
```

The user record in the user table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`, `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`, `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`) VALUES
('%', 'designjazzsu', '*812A9EC8DA3040D2FBE1FDE5A71B25011F43A358', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The contents of /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Tue Mar 25 10:57:08 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [789031949:87191570991]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [261535305:1869618743997]
#-A INPUT -s 88.88.88.88 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar 25 10:57:08 2014
```

When I try to telnet to the linux server with mysql on (99.99.99.99) on port 3306 it times out, this happens on the windows server (88.88.88.88) and also from my local office PC.

On the windows server the contents of my db.php include (this is the server that is trying to connect to the linux mysql) looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "99.99.99.99";
$user = "designjazzsu";
$password = "52dJ5rH6kL77hgd!";
$db = "designjazzsetup";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
#echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("99.99.99.99", $user, $password, $db, 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

#echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

I have spent over a day on this and am completely stuck.

I have a database on the linux server that needs to be shared between both servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

And thanks.

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind on two addresses.
You can bind on 0.0.0.0 address and make rules in firewall.
Example and useful links:

[unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/)

[mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address)

Comment: So I want to use the mysql server on the linux box for both local connections i.e. websites with databases hosted in the linux box but I also want to remote connect in from the windows server to access the databases from websites hosted on the windows server. Also the firewall in plesk for MySQL server is saying Allow incoming from all.

Comment: If you want to remote connect you have to comment bind-address. In another way you can't connect remote - only from defined IP.

Comment: I have tried it without the bind address as well and still it doesn't work.

Comment: After comment bind-address, did you restart MySQL server?

Comment: Yes with /etc/init.d/mysqld restart

Comment: Stupid question: did you save a file? :)
Seriuos question: can you connect to mysql from another program? MySQL workbench, navicat or other?

Comment: I have read through both the links you provided both IceManSpy and tried the changes in there but still not successful.

Comment: But did you to connect from another program like MySQL workbench or navicat?
If yes, maybe you have problem with firewall ?
Any logs from MySQL?

Comment: 140326  5:13:30 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
140326  5:13:30 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
140326  5:13:30 [ERROR] Aborting

140326  5:13:30 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140326 05:13:30  mysqld ended

Comment: You can see, that you have used 3306 port (default for MySQL). Maybe change for another?

Comment: Hi I tried that set it to port 3307 and nothing. I have also enabled logging again but doesn't seem like the log file is being udpated with new records.